# Python defaultdict: switching default creation on / off?

Tags: python, defaultdict

Is there a way to switch a defaultdict from permissive into strict mode and back again?

Update after first comment: without "trivially" converting to a standard dict, as this may lead to memory problems for dicts with hundreds of millions of entries.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# population time, be permissive
d = defaultdict(lambda: [])
for i in range(1,10):
    d[i].append(i + 1)

# d.magic()     # magic switch, tell d to be strict
print(d[1])     # OK, exists
print(d[111])   # I'd like to have an error here, please
```

Comment: You can trivially do `d = dict(d)`. Also note that `lambda: []` is provided more readably by `list`.

Comment: Totally valid, I just forgot to mention I need that for humongous dicts where interconversion could result in memory problems.

Comment: Then write your own `defaultdict` equivalent; you can see the existing API [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), and there's no `.magic`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a regular dictionary instead. Simpler and works, since you only need the "default" functionality within a strictly limited context. In that limited context, use `dict.setdefault`:

```
d = {}
for i in range(1, 10):
    d.setdefault(i, []).append(i+1)
```